# Setting up a server with only subdomains, any connection to top level goes to main server on another IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, virtualhost

I'm developing a web app where users will have their own sub-domain to login to and use the application. I'm running wordpress for the main website to manage the public / front end. Our application is developed in zend framework. The zf project is currently in a subfolder on the main server.

I'd like to place the zend framework project onto another server (different IP) and keep it separate from the the wordpress front end www.domain.com site.

The zf application server will run nginx. I'm not sure how to setup a server to run strictly sub domains. Setting up the virtual hosts in the configuration file is no problem. To give the users username.domain.com. But what about the main default configuration file? How would that be configured since the top level domain is technically another server (wordpress) on another IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just dont setup the main domain as an nginx vhost on the subdomain server and leave the dns pointing at the old server.

you then setup vhosts for the subdomains (or catch all subdomains depending on your application) and point dns at your subdomain server

so i'm guessing dns will look something like this:

example.com A 123.456.789.123
www.example.com A 123.456.789.123
sub.example.com A 123.456.789.124
sub2.example.com A 123.456.789.124
etc ...

its that simple, the main default config file doesnt need to be edited, in fact you could remove it if you wanted (although i would suggest leaving it and setting its server name to localhost and as default so that any subdomains not listened to get a default page :)

Comment: I thought I would need a default site enabled. Another question in regards to DNS. If I used a wildcard A record *.example.com, for sub domains that don't exist can I do a Redirect for 404's to a custom page rather than have them resolve to whatever they would example.com possibly not sure. But rather than asdfasdf.example.com resolving send requests to a custom 404?

Comment: as long as the wildcard vhost was last read config file or you did that as part of a generic default vhost that wont be an issue at all, because it will look for a match first before reverting to the default vhost - a default vhost is not required, but if its not specified you wont get consistent behaviour on non matching server names

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue correctly, you can do it via DNS if you are going to have a few user base. Still having DNS changes for every user is cumbersome and involves time for propagation. If the user base is huge, then you can choose a domain.com/ format & then redirect the requests accordingly to the remote IP using a PHP script.

Comment: Yes we'll have a large user base so new A records for every subdomain isn't really an option. I'm thinking of using a wildcard on my main domain and would like to catch 404s for subdomains that dont have a virtual host setup and redirect them. I prefer not redirect visitors and get them to their page the first time.